# Jquery validate input number float without plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

Max number 999999.9. 
User can input:

- 1. -> 1
- .5 -> 0.5
- 5.568 -> 5.6
- as -> alert
- empty -> will be ok
- spacebar -> empty, will be ok

```
$('.sq input').unbind().blur( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var v = $(this).val();
    var regex = /^[0-9]?\d{0,5}[\.,]?\d{0,1}$/g;
    switch(id)
    {
        case 'id_sq_pl':
            if ( regex.test(v) || v == '' ) {
                $(this).val(v);
            } else {
                alert('Number need');
            }
            // console.log(v);
        break;
        // other case id
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PXY4u/6/

It's good: http://jsfiddle.net/PXY4u/7/ but here input not type="number"
if i add to input type="number" it`s don`t working

Comment: What is the **question**?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 function numberTest( value) 
{
  return  /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```